# Any way to extract/cut a common string out of 2 different strings?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is Bash or Linux command for extracting the common string out of 2 partly similar, partly different strings

how to get variable

```
a="How good is it to"
```

out of

```
b="How good is it to die in defending fatherland"
c="How good is it to live in dedicating oneself to nation"
```

Comment: Why is the word `to` not included in the string that you want to extract?  What about the word `in`?

Comment: What about the trailing space?

Comment: Does the order of the words matter? What should the two strings `a b c 1 2 3` and `a b 1 2 c 3` result in?

Comment: Yes, only the sequence of consecutive words are demanded

Comment: Did any of the answers solved your problem? If not, let us know; otherwise, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With a bash loop over the strings:

```
i=0
a=
while [[ ${b:i:1} == ${c:i:1} ]]; do a+=${b[i]}; ((++i)); done
```

Or, with less manipulation:

```
i=0
while [[ ${b:i:1} == ${c:i:1} ]]; do ((++i)); done
a=${b:0:i}
```

Note that this results in the string:

```
printf -- '-->%s<--\n' "$a"
-->How good is it to <--
```

... with the trailing space, since that character is common to both source strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
b="How good is it to die in defending fatherland"
c="How good is it to live in dedicating oneself to nation"
a=()
count=0
for i in ${b[@]}
do
        if [ "`echo "${c[@]}" | grep $i`" ]; then
                a[count]=$i
                count=$((count+1))
        fi
done
echo ${a[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i have redirected value of variable  "a" and "b" to file "file1" and "file2"

Below is command i have used to fetch the common strings
```

Let me know for any suggestions or corrections

```
for i in {1..13}; do awk -v i="$i" 'NR==FNR{a[$i];next}($i in a){print $i}' file1 file2 ; done|sed '/^$/d'| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
How good is it to in
```

Comment: the OP did not show the word "in" as sample output...